# Parameterization of $\,y=\frac A{x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to parameterize the curve $\,y=\dfrac{A}{x^2}\,$ where $A$ is a constant and I have something that works but I'm not sure why. The parameterization of the curve is $\left(\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{A}{t}}\;,\,\sqrt[3]{t^2A}\right)$.

Can anyone help me understand why this works? I'm pretty lost at this point. I'm not even sure which branch of math would be best to field this question to but I've tagged a couple of different ones that I think deal with problems like this a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works because if you take the equation $y=A/x^2$ and replace $y$ with $(A/t)^{1/3}$ and $x$ with $\root3\of{t^2A}$ you get an equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y = \frac {A}{x^2}$ then  $x^2y = A$

So plugging $x = \sqrt [3]{\frac {A}{t}}, y=\sqrt [3]{A t^2}$

We indeed get that $x^2y = A$

But this is hardly the only parameterization that works.

$x = t, y = \frac {A}{t^2}$ is probably the most obvious parameterization.

or $x = \frac {1}{t}, y = At^2$ would also work.

Comment: So parameterizing a curve is really just trying to figure out what makes the equality work? I guess I never realized parameterization was so open-ended and was expecting some other formulaic reason for it. Thank you!

Comment: There are multiple parmaterizations for any curve.  e.g. if you want to parameterize the unit ciricle, $x = \cos t, y = \sin t$ is obvious, but you could also use $x = \cos \omega t, y = \sin \omega t.$ But $x = \frac {1-t^2}{1+t^2}, y = \frac {2t}{1+t^2}$ also works.